# how to implement a method to print the indices of next smaller element (in java)?

Tags: java, arrays

```java
public int[] nextSmallerNumber(int[] array){}
```

Given an array of integers, return an array containing the indices of the next smaller number of every number or -1 if the next smaller number does not exist.

Example for clarification :

```
input: 10, 9, 2, 7, 6, 1, 2
output: 1, 2, 5, 4, 5, -1, -1
(((the algorithm should run in O(n) time)))
```

my code

```
 public void nextSmallerNumber(int[] array) {
        int next, i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            next = -1; 
            for (j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
                if (array[i] > array[j]) { next = array[j]; }}
            System.out.println(i + " , " + next); }
    }
```

but it I can't handle -1 case and I can't make it in O(n).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void nextSmallerNumber(int[] arr) 
    { 
        Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer>(); 

          int n=arr.length

        s.push(arr[0]); 

        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) { 

        if (s.empty()) { 
            s.push(arr[i]); 
            continue; 
        } 

    while (s.empty() == false && s.peek() > arr[i]) { 
            System.out.println(s.peek() + " --> " + arr[i]); 
            s.pop(); 
        } 

        s.push(arr[i]); 
        } 

            while (s.empty() == false) { 
        System.out.println(s.peek() + " --> " + "-1"); 
        s.pop(); 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: I run it and the outputs are different!

Comment: could you elaborate.?